# Can't seem to get class_exists to work

Tags: php, jquery, css, class

I have a page setup where some of the divs have the class `.w2` and others don't, as I need these items to have a different image size. So I have been looking around to see what I could use to check if a class is applied and found the `class_exists` function.

So I have been doing a little test first to see how it works, but it always returns `false`. This is the same even if I try to see if the page has the class `item` applied which each of the div elements do, but it still returns `false`.

```
<div class="item w2">
    <?php
        if (class_exists('w2')) {
            echo "The class is applied!";
        } else {
            echo "This class is not applied";
        }
    ?>
<div>
```

Thanks for any suggestion to this.

/* EDIT */

I have been thinking about this some more and really I don't need to be adding another class to every other div. I just need to select every other div. So I was thinking that I could use the :nth-child(even) selector instead. Trying it out with the code below works, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of writing the markup?

```
jQuery(function() {
  if ($("#grid .item:nth-child(even)")) {
    $(".item:nth-child(even) .figure h2").css('background', 'red');
  } else {
    $(".figure h2").css('background', 'blue');
  }
});
```

Thanks for all the helpful answers with this post.

Comment: `class_exists()` is nothing to do with css classes, and everything to do with [PHP's OOP classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: You could easily do this using jQuery's `hasClass()` method, but that happens client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

In response to your second question in your edit....

```
$( "div:odd" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
$( "div:even" ).css( "background-color", "blue" );
```

---

You are checking for a PHP class existing,  not a CSS class.  You want to use jQuery for this.

```
if ($(".w2").length > 0) {

    alert('class exists');


    $(".w2").each(function() {
        //perform some logic on found elements
        $(this).doStuff();
    }); 
} else {

    alert('class does not exist');
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Thank you Notorious. I have added an edit to the original post with something else that I am trying to figure out.

Comment: If this answer was correct can you click the checkmark to the left of my answer and also the up arrow?   Thanks!   Glad I could help, I'll take a look at your edit now.

Comment: @MarGera332 Answered your second question as well.   That better get me an upvote and accept now.  :)  haha :P

Comment: Thanks Notorious. I don't think that I can up vote at the moment because I have only just started using stackoverflow?

Comment: Also do you know if it is possible to use php inside of jQuery? I am working in Wordpress and need to include all of this code inside of the loop. I want to be able to display different sizes images dependent on if the div is odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `class_exists` function is to check whether a class (in the OOP sense of the word) exists, not for CSS classes on the client-side. In fact PHP is strictly server-side and will have no knowledge at all of any of the HTML after it is generated.

To do what you require, you can use jQuery, like this:

```
<div class="item w2">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        if ($('.w2').length) {
            console.log('The class is applied!');
        }
        else {
            console.log('The class is not applied');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense now why it doesn't work. Thank you for taking the time to answer, and putting together an example. I will give this a go now and see how I get on.